# jquery how to find selector with similar ID in table row

Tags: jquery

I have a table that per row has some inputs and one edit button. I need to when user click edit button, I can get inputs value in this row and I do another action.
I use this code, but not work.

```
$("#editRowButton").click(function () {
     var currentTablerow = $(this).parent().parent();
     var txtNameValue = $(currentTablerow).find('input[id*="txtName"]').val();
});
```

My table structure like this

```
  <table id="Table2">
        <thead>
            <tr>
                <th>
                    Name
                </th>
                <th>
                    Family
                </th>
                <th>
                </th>
            </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
            <tr class="itemRow">
                <td>
                    <asp:TextBox Width="70px" ID="txtName" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
                </td>
                <td>
                    <asp:TextBox Width="70px" ID="txtFamily" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
                </td>
                <td>
                    <img id="editRowButton"  src="../Images/Edit.gif" />
                </td>
            </tr>
                    </tbody>
    </table
```

>
itemRow repeat by asp.net listview control
Problem occurs in below code

```
 var currentTablerow = $(this).parent().parent();
    var txtNameValue = $(currentTablerow).find('input[id*="txtName"]').val();
```

How i replace find by another solution

Comment: Can you show some HTML as well please

Comment: why dont you use class instead of id? id must be unique on page. if you want use some element with same name - use class - find('inpur.txtName')

Comment: could show us your html, your code seems ok

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Firstly, you cannot have multiple elements with the same ID. Secondly, it would be much easier to write the following code like so

```
$(".editRowButton").live('click', function () {
    // To get the closest parent element that is a table row
    var currentTablerow = $(this).closest('tr');
    // To get all of the inputs
    var inputs = currentTablerow.find('input');

    // use the values
    alert(inputs.filter('.name').val());
});
```

This also means that your html should resemble something like

```
<tr>
    <td><input type="text" class="name" /></td>
    <td><input type="text" class="email" /></td>
    <td><button class="editRowButton">Edit</button></td>
</tr>
```

Comment: For reasons I can not use class selector

Comment: There are no sane reasons why you can't use class selectors.

Comment: I use your sample code but last line code (alert) return undefined.

Comment: Sorry, there should be  `alert(inputs.filter('.name').val());` instead of `alert(inputs.find('.name').val());`. Fixed it in the above code.

Answer (score 0):

In this code, what happens if that find call returns more than 1 input field? You can't get the value from an array like that, you would need to loop over it and do something with each value.

Further, what doesn't work? Maybe you can put a concise example on http://jsfiddle.net/

Comment: Not find any input, it returns undefined.